# Change Background image once at 6 AM and other at 6 PM

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two images one for morning which I need to display it after 6am and other for night which I need to display it at background after 6pm.  Please help me in changing the display automatically at 6am-6pm and 6pm-6am .

```
NSDate *_currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *_dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd' 06:00AM +0000'"]; // set the morning date here
NSString *_morningDateString = [_dateFormatter stringFromDate:_currentDate];
[_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd' 06:00PM +0000'"]; // set the evening date here
NSString *_eveningDateString = [_dateFormatter stringFromDate:_currentDate];

[_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mma zzz"];
NSDate *_morningDate = [_dateFormatter dateFromString:_morningDateString];
NSDate *_eveningDate = [_dateFormatter dateFromString:_eveningDateString];

NSTimeInterval _intervalToMorningDate = [_morningDate timeIntervalSinceDate:_currentDate];
NSTimeInterval _intervalToEveningDate = [_eveningDate timeIntervalSinceDate:_currentDate];

if (_intervalToMorningDate > 0) {
    // now it is night
    self.bgImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"main_bg.png"];
   [self performSelector:@selector(replaceTheBackgoundForMorning) withObject:nil afterDelay:_intervalToMorningDate];
} else {
    // now it is daytime
    self.bgImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"daylight.png"];
    [self performSelector:@selector(replaceTheBackgoundForEvening) withObject:nil afterDelay:_intervalToEveningDate];
}
-(void)replaceTheBackgoundForMorning {
// reaplce the backgound here
self.bgImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"daylight.png"];
}

- (void)replaceTheBackgoundForEvening {
// reaplce the backgoung here
self.bgImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"main_bg.png"];
}
```

Comment: This seems way too complicated.  Just create an NSTimer that ticks every minute and in the timer handler look at the current hour and set the image as appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `NSDateComponents` like below

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger nowHour = [components hour];
NSInteger nowMinute = [components minute];
NSInteger nowSecond = [components second];

if (nowHour < 6 || (nowHour > 18 || (nowHour == 18 && (nowMinute > 0 || nowSecond > 0)))) {
   // Time is 6pm to 6am
}
else{
    // Time is 6am to 6pm
```

Comment: thankS!! it is working but after reaching 6pm it does not changing the image automaticaaly. I have to run the app to change the image.